# Delete all lines containing alphabetic characters in N++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, letters

I'm on clearing up my proxy list for special tool, which doesn't understand proxy addresses containing alphabetical characters. So i need to delete all lines from the proxy list, which contain letters.

To find letters is no problem: `([a-z])` does the trick. But how can should i find / markup the whole line ? And what should i use to replace the line containing letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of Notepad++ mark feature.

First open the mark dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
 and switch to Mark), check *Mark line* and *Regular expression*. Then *Find all* with the pattern `[[:alpha:]]+`

[image: Mark dialog]

Now all lines with a letter should have a bookmark in front. You can now go to *Search* -> *Bookmark* -> *Remove bookmarked lines*

Comment: With this approach, you may use `[[:alpha:]]` without a `+` quantifier. Or `\p{L}` (`\pL`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think it makes a huge difference, but the marking doesn't stop after the first occurance in a line, thus the search and mark might be executed more often without the `+` in case of repeated letters.

Comment: i haven't the option `mark line` in the `mark`-dialog. i use n++ 6.9.2 on win7. Where do you get it from?`is it an extension? Damn, its weird - this option is missed if german translated interface is in use!

Comment: Added a screenshot - I don't believe it's from a plugin, though not sure.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a solution to use with the Find and Replace feature and anywhere else in Notepad++ to match any line containing a letter**.

Matching a whole line with an ASCII letter in it:

```
^.*[a-zA-Z].*$\R?
```

A `\R?` at the end allows also matching a line break (optionally).

To make it more efficient, use a `[^a-zA-Z\r\n]` negated character class in the beginning:

```
^[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z].*$\R?
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*` - 0 or more characters other than ASCII letters and LF/CR
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `.*$` - zero or more characters other than a newline up to the end of line
- `\R?` - optional linebreak

Here, one line `333333ge3444444444` was removed:

[image]

Comment: Also, any letter can be matched with `\p{L}` pattern.

Comment: `^.*[a-zA-Z].*$\R?` this marks me the whole content, all lines

Comment: Only if you have *`.` matches newline* option ON. It must be OFF. I added a screenshot.